# Testing for plateau with discrete timepoints

Tags: hypothesis-testing, constrained-regression

I have measured a continuous outcome at 4 timepoints (t1, t2, t3, t4), spaced evenly apart. The measurements at each time point are on different groups (i.e. the responses at t1 come from all different subjects than at t2, t3, t4). The scientific question is whether the mean of the outcome plateaus or decreases at some point before t4. I think a time i would be defined as a plateau if mu_j < mu_i for j < i and mu_i >= mu_k for k > i. My questions are:

1. Is there a way of performing a hypothesis test for a plateau occurring sometime before t4? I think the null hypothesis here would be that mu_1 < mu_2 < mu_3 < mu_4, i.e. that the mean is monotonically increasing.
2. Is there a way of performing a test to determine which time point the plateau occurs at?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some representative, reporducible data.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a range of *x* values you could use a model like a linear-plateau model or quadratic-plateau model.

However with only four categories on the x-axis, this kind of approach won't be feasible.

One approach would be to use --- if appropriate --- a one-way anova model, and use an appropriate post-hoc test to compare among the four groups.  A non-parametric analogue would be a Kruskal-Wallis test followed by Dunn (1964) test.

Results from the post-hoc test could give evidence that e.g. *C* is statistically different from *D*.

This approach may or may not give the results we want.

I created a toy example.  Toy data and a plot of means and confidence intervals follows.

Here, the values for *D* are overall greater than those of *C*, but the difference isn't as large as that between *A* and *B*, and *C* and *D*.  For these data, we can't conclude that *C* and *D* are different.  So, by my method, we might say *C* and *D* are the plateau.  But the plot does suggest that the mean values continue to increase from *C* and *D*, if at a lower rate.  Is this a plateau or not.  I'm not sure.

Another idea is to use polynomial contrasts or other post-hoc contrasts to make meaningful comparisons among the time categories. I included some below.  But I'm not sure they make perfect sense for detecting a plateau across categories.

A *linear* trend suggests that, here, the means to increase across the categories.  A *quadratic* trend might be significant if there is a plateau or if there is a decrease in e.g. the final category.

You could also compare among the categories in groups.  Here I compare (A vs. B, C, D); (B vs. C, D); and (C vs. D).  The results suggest that there is an increase in values across the categories, but not for (C vs. D).  This might be the best approach for this case.

[image]

```
A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
B = c(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
C = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
D = c(12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

Y = c(A,B,C,D)
Group = factor(
        c(rep("A", length(A)), 
          rep("B", length(B)),
          rep("C", length(C)),
          rep("D", length(D)))
          )

Data = data.frame(Group, Y)

library(rcompanion)

Sum = groupwiseMean(Y ~ Group,
                    data   = Data,
                    conf   = 0.95,
                    digits = 3)

Sum

   ###   Group  n Mean Conf.level Trad.lower Trad.upper
   ### 1     A 10  5.5       0.95       3.33       7.67
   ### 2     B 10  9.5       0.95       7.33      11.70
   ### 3     C  9 14.0       0.95      11.90      16.10
   ### 4     D  9 16.0       0.95      13.90      18.10


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Sum,                ### The data frame to use.
       aes(x = Group,
           y = Mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Trad.lower,
                    ymax = Trad.upper),
                width = 0.05,
                size  = 0.5) +
  geom_point(shape = 15,
             size  = 4) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title   = element_text(face  = "bold")) +
  ylab("Y")


model = lm(Y ~ Group, data=Data)

library(car)

Anova(model)

   ### Anova Table (Type II tests)
   ###
   ###           Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
   ### Group     630.89  3  25.088 9.604e-09 ***

library(emmeans)

marginal = emmeans(model,~ Group)

pairs(marginal, adjust="none")

   ###  contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
   ###  A - B        -4.0 1.29 34  -3.089  0.0040
   ###  A - C        -8.5 1.33 34  -6.390  <.0001
   ###  A - D       -10.5 1.33 34  -7.893  <.0001
   ###  B - C        -4.5 1.33 34  -3.383  0.0018
   ###  B - D        -6.5 1.33 34  -4.886  <.0001
   ###  C - D        -2.0 1.36 34  -1.465  0.1520

levels(Data$Group)     

Contrasts = list(linear          = c(-3, -1,  1, 3),
                 quadratic       = c( 1, -1, -1, 1),
                 compareA.BCD    = c(-3,  1,  1, 1),
                 compareB.CD     = c( 0, -2,  1, 1),
                 compareC.D      = c( 0,  0, -1, 1))

contrast(marginal, Contrasts, adjust="none")

   ###       contrast     estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
   ###   linear             36 4.21 34   8.558  <.0001
   ###   quadratic          -2 1.88 34  -1.063  0.2952
   ###   compareA.BCD       23 3.20 34   7.186  <.0001
   ###   compareB.CD        11 2.28 34   4.817  <.0001
   ###   compareC.D          2 1.36 34   1.465  0.1520
```

Comment: P.S. For an example of a clear plateau, change, `B = c(12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)`.  For an example of clearly no plateau, change, `D = c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)`.